# How to get type of implemented class inside the interface?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, interface

I have `Group<t>` class:

```
public class Group<t> where t : IGroupable
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IList<t> Members { get; set; }
}
```

but I have problem with defining the `IGroupable` interface.

The problem is since I want to have a many-to-many connection in database, the `IGroupable` should contain `IList<Group<t>> Groups { get; set; }` where `t` is the type if the class that implemented the interface.

Comment: What is the problem? Also, are you using Entity Framework?

Comment: @haim770 Yes. I'm gonna use EF Code First for database part.

Comment: Entity Framework won't allow you to use generic types as your *concrete* Entities. They can inherit abstract generic classes, but cannot be generic themselves.

Comment: @haim770 I'm not sure if I understood. I have a `center` class and some other classes. in `Center`, I have `IList<Group<Center>> Groups` the reason that I'm trying to have that group is that I define many-to-many connection between group and IGroupable instead of having almost same code int different places. Are you saying that It's not possible to define many-to-many connections between Group<t> and IGroupable?

Comment: I'm saying 2 things: **1.** Your entities cannot be generic themselves (cannot have the `<t>` in the class definition), but they *can* implement/inherit other types that are generic. **2.** EF doesn't support mapping of interface types, you'll have to change your `IGroupable` to an abstract class (`Groupable`?) then define relationships on both sides as `IList<Groupable>`.

Comment: @haim770 My point of creating these generic class and interface was that I wanted to have separate Grouping for each part (Centers, Persons). But if I have a Group and a Groupable, it means that all of the groups will store in a table and It will be hard to separate them.

Comment: No, you can configure the inheritance of `Grouping` to be Table-Per-Type (TPT) then have each type in its own table.

Comment: @haim770 you mean that I inherit `Groupable` in `Center`?

Comment: Yes. Something like `CenterGroupable : Groupable`.

Comment: @haim770 I did something a little different. I removed `public IList<t> Members { get; set; }` and I have ` CentersGroup : GroupBase` instead. Thanks anyway ;)